# What is meant by modal events in Android?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

'A dialog does not fill the screen and is normally used for modal events that require users to take an action before they can proceed.'  The above text is from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html . What is meant by modal events?

Comment: Before you ask that you should understand first on **What is a Modal!** and it would be easier for you to understand that event.

Answer (score 2):

A modal dialog forces the user to interact with the dialog before going back to the application or activity the user was interacting with in the first place.

Basically a modal dialog or is used to get essential user input before continuing the application. The user cannot proceed with the application without dealing with the dialog first.

So back to the question, a **modal event** would be an event where application interaction is blocked, often while awaiting essential user input.

You can find more information [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Comment: The OP is asking for Modal *event* but explaining on what is a model is a good way also.